# Perl regex to replace windows path in line

Tags: regex, windows, perl

..without using an XML parser  - I just have this one line that needs the windows path name to be replaced with just the filename

I'm struggling to get the replacement regex

e.g.

```
<ImageTexture url='"C:\Users\HP\Documents\Dropbox\Preservation3d\linder\model_texture.jpg"'/>
```

has to become

```
<ImageTexture url='"model_texture.jpg"'/>
```

Comment: You can't replace string with regex, only match them. By the way you can use the regex "\D+\\"  to find the part to delete

Comment: Why would you not use an XML parser?

Comment: I would guess because there's download/installation restrictions, and neither Active nor Strawberry ship with one. Which is a pity, because it's absurdly easy with a parser.

Comment: @Sobrique, I though SP came with XML::LibXML? The front page specifically says it includes an XML library. As for AP, `ppm install XML::LibXML` installs XML::LibXML.

Comment: @Sobrique: Strawberry Perl ships with both `XML::Twig` and `XML::LibXML`

Comment: Ah, ok. I stand corrected. I can't remember now why I don't use SP. But perhaps the OP is using Active anyway, which I'm at least fairly sure still doesn't. (Although I might just go download the latest version and check)

Comment: @Sobrique, I didn't try with the latest, but I just did `ppm install XML::LibXML` with 5.16.3 built for MSWin32-x64-multi-thread and it was successful.

Comment: XML::LibXML broke in more recent versions of Active, and I don't think they've repackaged. https://code.activestate.com/ppm/XML-LibXML/ but not test report for 5.22 yet. (And the cpan download doesn't work without some serious effort). But if strawberry installs it by default, that's often easier to convince change managers about.

Answer (score 3):

The path leading up to the file will end with "`:`", "`\`" or "`/`", and none of those characters are legal in file names, so

```
( my $fn = $qfn ) =~ s{^.*[:\\/]}{}s;
```

or

```
use Path::Class::File qw( );

my $fn = Path::Class::File->new_foreign('Win32', $qfn)->basename();
```

On Windows, you can also use

```
use Path::Class qw( file );

my $fn = file($qfn)->basename();
```

or

```
use File::Basename qw( basename );

my $fn = basename($qfn);
```

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the comments. I can use XML::Parser  (using perl, v5.10.1 (*) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi btw)  but wanted a quickn'dirty with regex  - I'll try out basename ikegami, thanks a bunch

Comment: @Easycoder: What's the problem with using a proper module?

Comment: Hi Borodin, not a problem - just don't need the baggage

Comment: @ikegami that first solution worked great - thank you!